# How to configure UserDetailsChecker for preAuthenticationChecks and postAuthenticationChecks in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm searching for a 'best practice' solution for configuring a `UserDetailsChecker` for preAuthenticationChecks and/or postAuthenticationChecks in Spring Boot (see `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` and `DaoAuthenticationProvider`).

Is it absolute necessary to create a custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider`?

No way to customize it via `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question: I've searched the spring boot sources (v1.5.13.RELEASE and v2.0.2.RELEASE) with `grep` - no results.

At least in this versions you have to create a custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider` if you want to make use of additional pre- or post authentication checks.

Edit: The phrase "you have to create a custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider`" is a bit misleading. In a recent project I've done it in the following way:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth,
            MyUserAccountService myUserAccountService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor
    ) throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserAccountService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPostAuthenticationChecks(new UserAccountChecker(messageSourceAccessor));
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserAccountService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

[...]

}
```

Here `UserAccountChecker implements UserDetailsChecker` is a class where the (post) authentication tests take place (also see the class `DefaultPostAuthenticationChecks` in `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`).

Comment: And what is the next step after you extend `DaoAuthenticationProvider` ? which methods do you override? I'm particularly interested for post-authentication checks.

Comment: I do not extend `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, its the one from spring and handles the authentication checks (pre and post) in `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` (which is extended by `DaoAuthenticationProvider`).